# How to install implementation of Corba on my computer and then program using any language compatible with Corba

Tags: corba

I have to do a project in Corba.I have absolutely zero knowledge of corba.Things that I've to do is first is to install a corba implementation on my PC.After that I have to develop a Photo Printing Portal in any programming language supported by Corba.After that I have to deploy my application on the supplied ORB.
Please suggest how should I go about doing this.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention any programming language.
In case it is C++, I highly recommend to read the book [Advanced CORBA Programming with C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379279)

Answer (score 0):

It may be an idea to get Java on one side and C++ on another side talking with each other, using CORBA.

In addition to that @lothar recommends, you could install Eclipse and develop in Java. Java has CORBA support. [JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/) has been used by some as more stable and reliable alternative but this was ten years ago and probably many Sun's CORBA bugs at that time are already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For C++, you can try ACE-TAO version. It has many examples in

```
   ACE_wrappers/TAO/examples
```

Besides, there are many script supported Corba, such as R2Corba, omniORBpy.. I also have one Corba supported Tcl version which is not useful for you due to license restriction(But there is do some open source version).

I believe script corba is more appliable for your since less code is required..